# Display string included in elf file

Tags: linux, elf

I am trying to analyze elf files.
Is there a way to display all the string literals contained in the .rodata section of the elf file?

Comment: Did you look at the `strings` command?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to display all the string literals contained in the .rodata section of the elf file?

See [man strings](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html).

You could also use `readelf -x.rodata` or `objdump -sj.rodata`